# PHP sanitize serialized AJAX/JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm sending form data to a PHP script via AJAX/JSON.

Put this together using online tutorials but it seems to be working fine.

I want to try to edit the PHP script to sanitize the received, serialized AJAX/JSON data before the data is inserted into email.

I've checked around on StackOverflow and more generally on the web but can't find a definitive answer that fits the scripts I'm working with.

The code I'm using is summarized below.

**jQuery** (abbreviated code)

```
if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {

var url = "contact.php";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (data)
    {
      ...
    }
```

**PHP** (abbreviated code)

Data received via AJAX is placed into array:

```
$fields = array('client_name' => 'Name', 'client_phone' => 'Phone', 'client_email' => 'Email', 
'client_message' => 'Message');
```

Data is then placed into $emailText variable using foreach loop:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
// If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email 
if (isset($fields[$key])) {
    $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n\n";
}
}
```

Data sent in email:

```
mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, $headers);
```

**I'm wondering if there any way the serialized data can be extracted and sanitized in PHP before the email is sent?**

Say, with something like:

$sanitizedEmail = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: look into https://github.com/vlucas/valitron

Comment: @Nick Maroulis  -  Thanks, but valitron seems to be just another form validator app. I'm not sure what relevance it has to sanitizing JSON serialized data with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a few hours messing around with this and finally cracked it. Not sure if it is all perfectly written code - but hey, it works.

Probably a routine exercise for someone experienced with jQuery validation and AJAX but quite a mountain to climb for me.

I used the jbvalidator plugin in at:
[jbvalidator plugin](https://github.com/emretulek/jbvalidator)

... as well as Bootstrap 5.

Here's the finished, working code:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone" required>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
    </div>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send"><br>
    <div class="output_message"></div>
</form>
```

**jQUERY**

```
<script>

$(function (){

            let validator = $('form.needs-validation').jbvalidator({
                errorMessage: true,
                successClass: true,
                language: 
"https://emretulek.github.io/jbvalidator/dist/lang/en.json"
            });

            validator.reload();
            
            
            $(document).on('submit', '.needs-validation', function(){

                $.ajax({
                    method:"post",
                    url:"process-form.php",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (data){
                        
                            var alertBox = '<div class="alert alert-success 
alert-dismissable fade show" role="alert">Message sent. Thank you.           
<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria- 
label="Close"></button></div>';
                
                            $('.output_message').html(alertBox);
                            $('.needs-validation').trigger("reset");
                            $('.needs-validation input, .needs-validation 
textarea').removeClass("is-valid");
                        
                        if(data.status === 'error') {
                            
                            var errorBox = '<div class="alert alert-danger 
alert-dismissable fade show" role="alert">An error occurred. Please try again 
later.          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" 
aria-label="Close"></button></div>';
                
                            $('.output_message').html(errorBox);
                            $('.needs-validation').trigger("reset");
                            $('.needs-validation input, .needs-validation 
textarea').removeClass("is-valid");
                            
                        }
                    }
                })

                return false;
            });
})

</script>
```

**PHP**

Code can surely be improved but, like I said, for the moment it's working.

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['name'], $_REQUEST['email'])) {
  
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

    $sanitizedName = filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $sanitizedPhone = filter_var($phone, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $sanitizedEmail = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $sanitizedMessage = filter_var($message, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $email_message = "Name: " . $sanitizedName . "\n\n"
               . "Phone: " . $sanitizedPhone . "\n\n"
               . "Email: " . $sanitizedEmail . "\n\n"
               . "Message:\n\n" . $sanitizedMessage;
  
    $to = 'email@someplace.com';
  
    $subject = 'New message';
    
    $headers = 'From: admin@somedomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $sanitizedEmail . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  
    $send_email = mail($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers);
  
    echo ($send_email) ? 'success' : 'error';
}

?>
```

Cheers!